# Nested overlayareas

Tags: beamer, overlays

I want to have a series of slides, where the upper half is constantly the same picture. I would normally use two overlayareas to split the slide, but at some point I'd like to subdivide the bottom half again, as follows.

[image]

Is there some way I can subdivide an overlayarea into more overlayareas from one slide to the next?

PS: Just splitting the size of the bottom overlayarea still seems to produce some wobbling of the upper half, as happens in this example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{2cm}
        A
    \end{overlayarea}
    \only<1>{
        \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{2cm}
            B
        \end{overlayarea}
    }
    \only<2>{
        \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{1cm}
            C
        \end{overlayarea}
        \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{1cm}
            D
        \end{overlayarea}
    }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps simply put the `[t]` option after `\begin{frame}` to top-aligned the contents? This will solve the wobbling problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.5\textheight}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[height=.5\textheight]{example-image-a}
    \end{overlayarea}
  \only<1>{
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.5\textheight}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[height=.5\textheight]{example-image-b}
    \end{overlayarea}
  }
  \only<2>{
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.25\textheight}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[height=.25\textheight]{example-image-c}
    \end{overlayarea}
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.25\textheight}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[height=.25\textheight]{example-image-c}
    \end{overlayarea}
  }
  \only<3>{
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.25\textheight}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[height=.25\textheight]{example-image-a}
    \end{overlayarea}
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.25\textheight}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[height=.25\textheight]{example-image-b}
    \end{overlayarea}
  }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### No wobbling

Just enclose everything into an overlay area whose height is equal to the sum of the inner areas and the wobbling will go away:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame} 
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{4cm}       %new code
    \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{2cm}
        A
    \end{overlayarea}
    \only<1>{
        \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{2cm}
            B
        \end{overlayarea}
    }
    \only<2>{
        \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{1cm}
            C
        \end{overlayarea}
        \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{1cm}
            D
        \end{overlayarea}
    }
\end{overlayarea}    %new code
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but for some reason I still get some wobbling. In my case the "A" moves slightly upwards when going from the first to the second slide. That's why I wanted to fix the bottom half and subdivide it. But in your example it seems to work. Any idea why that might be so?

Comment: uhm... I can't seem to reproduce your issue. Do you experience the issue when copy/pasting my MWE into a new file and compiling as it is, or when you try to adapt the code to your content?

Comment: When I tried to adapt the code to my content. I am trying to just copy/paste your code, but I'm using lyx and don't know if I have the required figures. 

I am using a tikzpicture on the upper half and I'm subdividing the bottom half from 2.5cm to a 2cm and a 0.5cm area.

Comment: The figures are distributed with the mwe package, so if you have the package you should have them too. If I use some random figures I still get the same result shown above. There must be something somewhere else in your code that causes the wobbling. Would it be possible for you to set up a mwe that shows the problem so that I can reproduce it?

Comment: Ok, let me try.

Comment: I added a MWE. Basically the same as what you did, but with text instead of pictures produces some wobbling for me.

Comment: Ok, see the edit.

Comment: Excellent! It finally works.