# Nested overprint breaks preceding \onslide

Tags: beamer, overlays

The following `beamer` MWE consists of 5 slides. I use nested `overprint` environments to achieve overlay effects without wobbling spacing. On slides 2 and 3, the text "two and three" should appear, on slide 3 there should be an additional "three". Similarly on slides 4 and 5.

However, the second nested `overlay` environment seems to break the first `\onslide`; it just does not appear. A single nested `overprint` in the first `\onslide` works fine (comment the second nested overprint to see this).

Is `overprint` just not designed to be nested (I didn't find anything about this in the documentation) or is this a bug? How can I get around this without duplicating code?

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  Always

  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<2-3>
      two and three

      \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<3>
          three
      \end{overprint}

    \onslide<4-5>
      four and five

      \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<5>
          five
      \end{overprint}
  \end{overprint}

  Always
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If I put braces around the `\onslide` arguments, I get a somewhat different result. Can you test this and if possible explicitely state the output you would like ? I am not sure it is required to nest the `overprint`s here

Comment: A side-note, `overlayareas` can seemingly be nestes see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205177/nested-overlayareas for an example

Comment: @BambOo The result obtained by adding spaces is not quite what I want (the different stages of `overprint` are not actually printed over each other, i.e. in the same place, with braces). `overlayareas` may be a workaround, though I would really prefer not having to specify the height of the area.

Comment: So you want to print e.g. "two and three" and "four and five" on the same line, that's it ?

Comment: I just posted an answer that seems to fit your description of the desired output

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly using braces should solve your problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  Always

  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<2-3>{
      two and three}

      \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<3>{
          three}
      \end{overprint}

    \onslide<4-5>{
      four and five}

      \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<5>{
          five}
      \end{overprint}
  \end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Using the [textpos](https://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) package (absolute positioning)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay
%,showboxes
]{textpos}
\TPGrid{3}{5}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{textblock}{1}(0.5,2)
Always

\onslide<2-3>{two and three}

\onslide<3>{three}
    \end{textblock}

    \begin{textblock}{1}(0.5,2)
\invisible{Always}

\onslide<4-5>{four and five}

\onslide<5>{five}

Always
    \end{textblock}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is not quite what I wanted. The text "four and five \\ five" should occupy the same space as "two and three \\ three". (That's the point of the `overprint` environment.)

Comment: @schtandard Oh sorry! When I want get the effect that you want I use the [textpos package](https://ctan.org/pkg/textpos)

Answer (score 0):

After tweaking a bit the overlay specifications :

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  Always

  \begin{overprint}
    \only<1-3>{
      \onslide<2-3>{two and three

      \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<3>{
          three}
      \end{overprint}
      }
    }
    \only<4-5>{
      four and five

      \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<5>{
          five}
      \end{overprint}
    }
  \end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** : Correction of additional vertical spaces. These are likely due to inserted newlines by default. Adding the appropriate `%` as end of lines gives the expected result.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  Always

  \begin{overprint}
    \only<1-3>{%
      \onslide<2-3>{two and three

      \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<3>{three}%
      \end{overprint}%
      }%
    }%
    \only<4-5>{%
      four and five

      \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<5>{five}%
      \end{overprint}%
    }%
  \end{overprint}%

  Always
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While the output of this example looks like what I want at first glance, using `\only` in `overprint` instead of `\onslide` causes new problems. The height of the environment is the same as all of its content printed below each other. I added another line of text after the environment in the MWE to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @schtandard It seems to be due to newline insertion, more than the height of the `overprint`s. See the edit

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but there are still problems with this. When the different overlays do not have the same height, this gets "wobbly". Try for example to replace `five` by `five\\five\\five`. As I understand it, `overprint` really is only meant to be used with `\onslide` and anything else will break its functionality.

Comment: @schtandard Yes, unfortunately it seems you are right. The only way to go appears to be `\overlayarea`s